# Cargo builds with relative path dependencies using docker

Tags: docker, microservices, relative-path, rust-cargo, docker-multi-stage-build

We develop microservices in Rust and want to adopt the following repo structure

```
common-dep

 - Cargo.toml
 - src/

service-1

 - Cargo.toml
 - Dockerfile
 - src/

service-2
 - Cargo.toml
 ...

docker-compose.yml
```

The Cargo.toml files of the services contain a relative reference to the common dependency:

```
[dependencies]
common-dep = { path = "../common_dep", version=0.1 }
```

We use multi-staged docker builds. The problem is that the common dependencies are outside the workspace of Docker. Hence the build fails as Docker has no access to the common dependency.

What's the most elegant way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would consider packaging the common-dep in some place where it can be downloaded from (eg: git repo, crates.io or other privete package repository). Then change the Cargo.toml to not require it from a local path but to download it from an online source

Comment: Typically you need to set the build context to the parent directory of the service you're trying to build, then use paths relative to that in your Dockerfile (`COPY common-dep/Cargo.toml ./common-dep/` for example).  The linked question has more examples.